# Multi and index and sum panda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm pretty new to programming, and I'm learning on the fly, I've been trying to do this for a about an day now with no luck.  I have a pretty big dataset, it currently shows up like this:

server 1 policy 1    full2         1086 
server 1 policy 1    diff2         100.5 
server 3 policy 5    full3         500 
server 1 policy 3    app           10 
server 2 policy 2    full1         75 
server 2 policy 2    diff1         62

I need it to display like this 
|Client   |policy name |schedule name |volume

|server 1  |policy 1    |full2         |1086  
           |policy 1    |diff2         |100.5  
           |policy 3    |app           |10  
|total                                 |1196.5

|server 2  policy 2    |full2         |75  
          |policy 2    |diff1         |65  
|total                                |137

I've tried a bunch of different ways, group by doesn't seem to work it throws up a bunch of errors.  The values for everything except the volume field has an object value assigned to it.  The volume field is defined as a float64.
Like I said I'm pretty new at this so please bear with me if I'm not 100% understanding the concepts.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**. In this case, what would be useful is your latest attempt and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This code will calculate the totals by client

```
import pandas as pd

# |Client |policy name |schedule name |volume 
# server 1 policy 1 full2 1086
# server 1 policy 1 diff2 100.5
# server 3 policy 5 full3 500
# server 1 policy 3 app 10
# server 2 policy 2 full1 75
# server 2 policy 2 diff1 62

df = pd.DataFrame({'Client': ['server 1', 'server 1', 'server 3', 'server 1', 'server 2', 'server 2'],
                   'policy name': ['policy 1', 'policy 1', 'policy 5', 'policy 3', 'policy 2', 'policy 2'],
                   'schedule name': ['full2', 'diff2', 'full3', 'app', 'full1', 'diff1'],
                   'volume': [1086, 100.5, 500, 10, 75, 62]})

def print_with_and_total(df):
    print(df.groupby(['Client', 'policy name', 'schedule name']).sum())
    print('Total: {}'.format(df['volume'].sum()))

for x in df.groupby('Client'):
    print_with_and_total(x[1]) 

#                                     volume
# Client   policy name schedule name        
# server 1 policy 1    diff2           100.5
#                      full2          1086.0
#          policy 3    app              10.0
# Total: 1196.5
#                                     volume
# Client   policy name schedule name        
# server 2 policy 2    diff1            62.0
#                      full1            75.0
# Total: 137.0
#                                     volume
# Client   policy name schedule name        
# server 3 policy 5    full3           500.0
# Total: 500.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now is there a way to use that same command, to combine the display as well? Ideally I'd like to get the policy name and schedule name displayed as well. I tried something like this data.groupby(['Client','Policy Name','Schedule Name']).size().reset_index().groupby('client')[[0]].sum
but it threw up a bunch of errors.

Comment: It can be a little confusing. The groupby does not return another dataframe but an iterator over dataframes. Have updated answer to output in format you are looking for.